# responsive display in wordpress: managing columns on an iphone

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I'm using a twentytwelve wordpress child theme

my site is here: internalcompass.us/castle

Can I do anything to make both of the post columns on my homepage show up side by side when viewing my site on an Iphone? Tricky question, I know. Right now, the two columns just combine into one column if viewed on an Iphone.

I'd prefer the page to look like just like it the looks on the computer, only smaller. So I'd like the sidebar to display on the right as well. On the iphone, I have no sidebar at all right now.

Another designer said that this is an issue that requires me to look at media queries, which I believe is true, but after reading online, I'm not sure exactly how to apply that to this issue. I also looked at related posts here, but the info doesn't gel.

I know that the twenty twelve theme is responsive, and I understand I've modified the css somewhat to create these columns in my child theme. Is it even possible to have this site show up exactly as it does on the computer only smaller on the Iphone? Here is an example of a site that behaves that way when viewed on the iphone: leeabbamonte.com

He is using a totally different theme, so I'm just using it as a visual example. My theme is a twenty twelve child theme, and I can pastebin you to any page or paste code if that is helpful.

my site is at: internalcompass.us/castle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width” />
```

from your child themes header.php and add

```
#page { width:1000px }
```

to your child theme's css file. You can also choose another width, it just should be fixed. ;)

Comment: Thank you. I just deleted the first line of code you suggested, and it is now displaying correctly on the iphone. I have not yet done the #page width change yet. I appreciate this info very much and hope it can be useful to others!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with media queries.

As Example:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 480px) {
    #right-column,
    #left-column {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Maybe you have to deal a bit with the percentages based on your margin and paddings for each column.